# Making words break in table cells that are coming back dynamically

Tags: html, css

so a problem here that's sort of driving me crazy. So when the following data comes back from a service response, it displays in a table cell. I need to have it formatted in the cells and not have it as one long series of words. I tried word-break: break-all among a few other things but no dice

Sample CSS

```
.dataTable {

.maxwidth-300 {
  max-width:300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.maxwidth-100 {
  max-width:100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}}

  <p>Displays like this </p>
  <td maxwidth-300>Response : order|confirmed' email updated with status 'Sent'. (Email ID: 835) Subject: Order Confirmed: Order 11-001270 for Anna's Flower Shoppe From: Company Reply-to: blah@blahblah.com To: emailaddress@emailaddress.com Cc: emailaddress@emailaddress.com </td>
```

Is there a way to get it to display like this with CSS?

```
<td maxwidth-300>
'order|confirmed' email updated with status 'Complete'. (Email ID: 833)

Subject: Order Confirmation: Order 11-001270 for Anna's Flower Shoppe
From: Company 
Reply-to: blah@blahblah.com 
To: emailaddress@emailaddress.com
Cc: emailaddress@emailaddress.com </td>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I used JS to escape the JSON '\n' characters